# Xamarin.Android, Syncfusion.SfPicker has missing UpdatePopup function

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion.SfPicker for Xamarin.Android (https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-android/sfpicker/gettingstarted) and I'm using the latest version of the Syncfusion Nuget Library that contains the SfPicker.

My issue is that I receive the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object, at
>   Com.Syncfusion.SfPicker.SfPicker.UpdatePopup() [0x000d5] in
>   :0  at
>   Com.Syncfusion.SfPicker.SfPicker.set_IsOpen(System.Boolean value)
>   [0x00018] in <4cccb4f208d9407ca543d91156e77529>:0 at
>   MyTest_App.MainActivity.

When I execute following code in my MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    SfPicker picker = new SfPicker(this);
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    picker.IsOpen = true;
    SetContentView(picker);
}
```

Is the documentation wrong/missing stuff, or am I simply doing it wrong? I followed the code from the last example of the URL I linked above.

Hopefully someone can shine some light on what's the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the documentation wrong/missing stuff, or am I simply doing it wrong? I followed the code from the last example of the URL I linked above.

You could refer to the [Syncfusion Official Sample link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/GETTIN~1763331626.ZIP), to avoid this exception, you must give your `SfPicker` a `ItemsSource`.

For example,  create a `ColorInfo` class :

```
public class ColorInfo
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _color;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Colors
    {
        get { return _color; }

        set { _color = value; }
    }

    public ColorInfo()
    {
        Colors = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Colors.Add("Red");
        Colors.Add("White");
        Colors.Add("Orange");
        Colors.Add("Blue");
        Colors.Add("Purple");
        Colors.Add("Pink");
        Colors.Add("SkyBlue");
        Colors.Add("Yellow");
    }
}
```

Set `ItemSource` for your `SfPicker` :

```
SfPicker picker;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    picker = new SfPicker(this);
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ColorInfo info = new ColorInfo();
    picker.ItemsSource = info.Colors;

    picker.IsOpen = true;
    SetContentView(picker);
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, but now I tried to set the Picker as a Dialog instead, but then nothing happens. What's wrong?

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen, for a better solution, you could open a new question and post your code. :)